# MVC view first load - Is it better to set conditional div css in the html or javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am sending value from controller to view and I want to color it red if its zero.

Is it better to do it in html after zero check

```
@var redColor = Model.Number == 0 ? "redColor" : "";
<div class = @redColor id="number">
```

or in javascript during init

```
if($(#number).val() === 0)
{
   $(#number).addClass("redColor");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is Example, I'm using View Bag, then use in my Javascript , 
Ithink its better and more readability to use in javascript. . .
I'm also waiting Answer from Experienced Developer. . .

ActionMethod

```
  `public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Color = 1;
        return View();
    }`
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="colorMe"> 
    Blah blah
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
var num=@ViewBag.Color;
num == 1 ? $('#colorMe').css('background-color' ,'red') : '';
</script>
```